# ¿Que herramienta me recomiendan para hacer análisis de un algoritmo en PHP?(Tiempo de ejecución y memoria)

Tags: php, algoritmos, manejo-de-memoria, xdebug, complejidad

quisiera saber si saben de alguna herramienta o forma de medir los tiempos y el gasto de memoria de forma detallada de un algoritmo implementado en PHP, algo como el debugger de NetBeans para Java o el db de C++, no importa si tengo que cambiar el servidor.
PD: No me digan que no use PHP porque ya sé hacerlo con JS, Java, C++ y Python, pero estoy usando muco PHP últimamente y me sería útil saber hacerlo en un lenguaje para servidores.

Comment: Mejora te pregunta por favor pues no queda claro donde necesitas medirlo, para una consulta a una BD o para generar números aleatorios? Lee por favor [ask] pues así cómo está ahorita es muy amplia y basada en opiniones y terminará cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí se ofrecen un par de alternativas tanto para cpu como para memoria sin depender de ningún módulo externo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973037/benchmark-memory-usage-in-php

Para CPU se sugiere el uso de la instrucción [microtime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php) mientras que para medir la memoria se utilizan [register_tick_function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.register-tick-function.php) y [memory_get_ussage](http://php.net/manual/es/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Ten en cuenta que la solución con microtime te devolverá el tiempo 'real', pero quizás sería más interesante comparar el tiempo de cpu.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php) se discute como hacer profiling en php con algunas herramientas externas.

Finalmente, en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling) se explica como hacer profiling de memoria con Xdebug y también se habla de alguna alternativa (por si utilizaras php5, Xdebug dejó de soportar PHP 5 en la versión 2.6)

Espero que te sirva.